Can JSON Schema require one value equal another?
consider the following schema:
{
  "properties":{
    "a": { "type":"string"},
    "meta": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { /*what might I put here to require that obj.a == obj.meta.a?*/ }
      }
    }
  }
}

Can I require a == meta.a somehow?
Totally not required, and not even applicable to the case that led me to this question, but it'd also be interesting to know if I could do any operations, like substrings, or exponentiation (if a had been a number).

Out of the box, no.  JSON Schema doesn't define a way to reference parts of the instance, which means that it can't do those kinds of comparisons.
However, I have a data vocab that you might be able to use if you're in .Net.  I don't think any other languages support it yet.
Basically, you'd have
{
  "$schema": "https://json-everything.net/meta/data-2023",
  "properties": {
    "a": { "type":"string" },
    "meta": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "data": {
            "const": "/a"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

For this schema,
{
  "a": "string",
  "meta": {
    "a": "string"
  }
}

passes and
{
  "a": "string",
  "meta": {
    "a": "also string"
  }
}

fails.
What's happening is that the data keyword is building a schema by using its properties as keywords and dereferencing the values.  Plain JSON Pointers are resolved against the instance, so this effectively builds
{
  "const": "<whatever "a" is>"
}

in memory and evaluates meta.a against that.
You can test this at my playground https://json-everything.net/json-schema

You can make meta reference a so it's always the same data type as a. The only way to enforce it's the same value is by using const inside of a. Then it would be equivalent to {a: thing, meta: {a: thing}}
I'm not sure why you would ever do this though, just set the const in the meta object schema to whatever value you want.
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "properties":{
    "a": { "type":"string", "const": "thing"},
    "meta": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": {"$ref": "#/properties/a"} 
      }
    }
  }
}


"I'm not sure why you would ever do this though, just set the const in the meta object schema to whatever value you want", I don't want any particular value. I just need them to be the same.
